# How can I get hourly weather forecast in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, weather-api

I've seen some questions similar to this on here, but none of them seem to help me. I don't really care what API is used, be it Google, Yahoo!, The Weather Channel, or any other. I've got code that will get the high and low of the current day, based on the location given by the user, but I can't seem to get the hourly predictions for temperature or weather condition, which is what I'm really looking for. I don't really care for wind speeds, humidity, or the "feels like" temperature, though I'll add them if I can figure out how to. I'm trying to get data that will look something like what is here. [(www.weather.com/...)](http://www.weather.com/weather/hourbyhour/graph/New+York+NY+USNY0996:1%3aUS)

I'm pretty new to parsing XML so that may be part of my problem, too. Thanks in advance for any help. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: How are you doing it right now?

Comment: My code is very similar to DonA's but not nearly as detailed. I just had basic things like current temp, high and low temps.

Comment: The reason why I asked is because we need something to start with. If you don't even know the exact API you will be using, the answers might get too vague. Besides, had you given some code, we would better understand how to augment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for from [Weather Underground](https://www.wunderground.com/). They have three APIs, and, starting with the middle one, gives hourly forecasts for 36 hours. You get English and Metric predicted statistics for temperature, "feels like" temperature, dew point, wind speed, and wind direction. There's also wind chill and heat index, but every result for both in English and Metric was -9998, so I'm pretty sure those results are a bit off! Also there are qpf, snow, pop, and mslp. Unfortunately qpf and snow have not results and I'm not sure what pop and mslp are. All results are available in JSON and XML. They have some image requests, too, but I haven't looked into them yet.

**Update:**

Link Updated

Comment: That link is bad. Could you check it?

Answer (score 3):

I have something you might enjoy:

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Module Weather

Public Structure WeatherInfo_Forecast
  Dim DayOfWeek As String
  Dim low As Double
  Dim high As Double
  Dim icon As String
End Structure

Public Structure WeatherInfo_Wind
  Dim direction As String
  Dim speed As Double
  Dim unit As String
End Structure

Public Structure WeatherInfo_Typed
  Dim Failed As Boolean
  Dim errormessage As Exception
  Dim location As String
  Dim forcast_date As DateTime
  Dim checked_time_date As DateTime
  Dim humidity As Double
  Dim highf As Double
  Dim lowf As Double
  Dim highc As Double
  Dim lowc As Double
  Dim currenttempC As Double
  Dim currenttempF As Double
  Dim predicted_icon As String
  Dim current_icon As String
  Dim current_condition As String
  Dim predicted_condition As IEnumerable(Of WeatherInfo_Forecast)
  Dim wind_condition As WeatherInfo_Wind
  Dim day As String
End Structure

<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function ToC(ByVal F As Double) As Double
  Return ((F - 32) / 9) * 5
End Function

<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function TryParseAsDouble(ByVal s As String) As Double
  Dim rv As Double
  If Double.TryParse(s, rv) = False Then rv = Double.NaN
  Return rv
End Function

<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function TryParseAsDate(ByVal s As String) As DateTime
  Dim rv As DateTime
  If DateTime.TryParse(s, rv) = False Then rv = Nothing
  Return rv
End Function

Private Function ParseHumidity(ByVal s As String) As Double
  If Not s Is Nothing Then
  Dim humRegEx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("Humidity: (?<Value>\d+)\w*\%")
  Dim m = humRegEx.Match(s)
  If m.Length = 0 Then Return Double.NaN
    Return Double.Parse(m.Groups("Value").Value)
  End If
End Function

Private Function ParseWind(ByVal s As String) As WeatherInfo_Wind
  Dim rv As New WeatherInfo_Wind
  If Not s Is Nothing Then
    Dim humRegEx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("Wind\:\s+(?<Direction>[NEWSnews]{1,2})\s+at\s+(?<speed>(?<value>\d+)\s(?<units>\w+)){1}")
    Dim m = humRegEx.Match(s)
    rv.speed = Double.NaN
    If m.Length = 0 Then Return rv
    With rv
     .direction = m.Groups("Direction").Value
     If Double.TryParse(m.Groups("value").Value, .speed) = False Then .speed = Double.NaN
     .unit = m.Groups("units").Value
    End With
  End If
  Return rv
End Function

<DebuggerHidden()>
Public Function Grab_Weather(ByVal Location As String) As WeatherInfo_Typed
  Dim GrabWeather As New WeatherInfo_Typed
  With GrabWeather
  .Failed = True
  Try
    Dim xml As XDocument = XDocument.Load("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=" & Location)
    Dim xp = xml.<problem_cause>
    If xp.Any Then Return GrabWeather
    .location = xml...<city>.@data
    .forcast_date = xml...<forecast_date>.@data.TryParseAsDate
    .checked_time_date = xml...<current_date_time>.@data.TryParseAsDate
    .humidity = ParseHumidity(xml...<humidity>.@data)
    .highf = xml...<high>.@data.TryParseAsDouble
    .lowf = xml...<low>.@data.TryParseAsDouble
    .highc = GrabWeather.highf.ToC
    .lowc = GrabWeather.highc.ToC
    .currenttempC = xml...<temp_c>.@data.TryParseAsDouble
    .currenttempF = xml...<temp_f>.@data.TryParseAsDouble
    '.current_icon = "http://www.google.com" & xml...<icon>.@data
    '.predicted_icon = "http://www.google.com" & xml...<high>.@data
    .current_condition = xml...<condition>.@data
    .predicted_condition = From f In xml...<forecast_conditions> _
                        Select New WeatherInfo_Forecast With { _
                          .DayOfWeek = f.<day_of_week>.Value, _
                          .high = f.<high>.@data.TryParseAsDouble, _
                          .low = f.<low>.@data.TryParseAsDouble}
    '.icon = "http://www.google.com" & f.<icon>.@data}
    .wind_condition = ParseWind(xml...<wind_condition>.@data)
    .day = xml...<day_of_week>.@data
    .Failed = False
    Return GrabWeather
  Catch ex As Exception
    .errormessage = ex
    Return GrabWeather
  End Try
  End With
End Function
End Module
```

Comment: This was actually pretty close to what I had, but yours is more detailed. Also, I'm getting a 403 error from Google when I use your code. I thought I was thing and not getting it, but now that I've put my old code back, I'm getting it with that too. Odd... Thanks for your help though. This code has definitely been helpful.

Comment: It wasn't that long ago that it worked. I will check into that myself.

Comment: As I've done more digging I've found that Google's weather api is no longer functioning. I started this project a while back and decided to pick it up again yesterday. With little progress I posted this question. I should have done my homework a little better. Sorry. I'm now trying to look for another api to use but I haven't found one that provided the hourly forecasts that I'm looking for. I know Microsoft's doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at it a little a few minutes ago, but I don't think it has what I'm looking for. I wasn't able to find hourly predictions. Just the lows and highs of the next few days. Thanks for all your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know if any do that. The current temp does change, so it is just a matter of making hourly queries. You know how bad they are at predicting weather for daily events! How on earth do you expect them to predict it for future hours???

Comment: I'm looking for something like in the link in my original post. [(www.weather.com/...)](http://www.weather.com/weather/hourbyhour/graph/New+York+NY+USNY0996:1%3aUS) Weather.com and others provide this on their websites and in their apps. I want something like that. I know the data is out there. It's just a matter of whether or not any of the free APIs provide it.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for your help with all this, DonA. I appreciate it.